# nginx prerender doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, nginx, prerender

I tried with the follow configuration and it didn't work.
Prerender.io page stays with the message "We haven't seen a request with your Prerender token yet."
Obviously I replaced YOUR_TOKEN with mine
Someone can help me ?

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
 }

 location @prerender {
     proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

set $prerender 0;
if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
    set $prerender 1;
}
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
    set $prerender 1;
}
if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
    set $prerender 0;
}
if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
    set $prerender 0;
}

#resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
resolver 8.8.8.8;

if ($prerender = 1) {

    #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
    set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
    rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
    proxy_pass http://$prerender;
}
if ($prerender = 0) {
    rewrite .* /index.html break;
}
}   
}
```

Sorry for the identation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have @prerender in your try_files directive so @prerender won't be executed.

Also, if you are serving an index.html from the file system, sometimes try_files $uri will always match the index page so even if you add @prerender there it might not be executed. You might try something like:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }

     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
 }

}
```